# Chrome browser has trouble loading images after reload

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

My website is http://acclyrics.com

The site works great on all browsers, however, one very annoying bug keeps showing up. When you go to it on chrome, it works, but if you try refreshing the page, suddenly the page seems to enter a "load forever" mode, and the picture slider I made does not work past a few images. It starts coming up blank.

Again, this ONLY happens in chrome, which is very strange, since chrome has always been the best browser for me. Does this happen for anyone else? Any tips about fixing this / working around this would be greatly appreciated.

It's not a HUGE issue, because I don't see any reason why someone would be reloading the page anyway, but it's still irritating for me.

Here is the code for my picture slider. If you need to see any other code please ask:

```
function StartPictureSlider() {
    var NumberOfPics = 11;
    var b = 2;
    var c = document.getElementById('PictureSlider');

    setInterval(function () {
        if (b == 1) {
            var previouspicture = "pic" + NumberOfPics
        } else {
            var previouspicture = "pic" + (b - 1)
        };

        var newpicture = "pic" + b;

        document.getElementById(previouspicture).style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById(newpicture).style.display = "block";

        b++;

        if (b > NumberOfPics) {
            b = 1
        };
    }, 4000);
};
```

The pictures are loaded in a hidden style with HTML, so that the slider is just changing the display. Again, this works great on all the browsers, except for Chrome when refresh is hit.

```
<div id="PictureSlider" class="PictureSlider">
    <img src='pictures/1.png' id="pic1" alt='art work' />
    <img src="pictures/2.png" id="pic2" style="display:none" />
    <img src="pictures/3.png" id="pic3" style="display:none" />
    <img src="pictures/4.png" id="pic4" style="display:none" />
    <img src="pictures/5.png" id="pic5" style="display:none" />
    <img src="pictures/6.png" id="pic6" style="display:none" />
    <img src="pictures/7.png" id="pic7" style="display:none" />
    <img src="pictures/8.png" id="pic8" style="display:none" />
    <img src="pictures/9.png" id="pic9" style="display:none" />
    <img src="pictures/10.png" id="pic10" style="display:none" />
    <img src="pictures/11.png" id="pic11" style="display:none" />
</div>
```

Comment: done any debugging, like popping up the devel console to see what's going on? shift-ctrl-J

Comment: This might be pretty heavy, because mine crashed on the first refresh. And my PC and broadband are both excellent.

Comment: it's not really necessary to do your own slider if your're new to the javascript...
there are bunch of jquery libraries that could do this for you while adding a line or two of code

Comment: No, chrome does not show any bugs / errors of any kind (of course). And I don't use Jquery, only plain javascript.

Comment: Some issues: Your code have missing semi-colons and semi-colons where they're not needed. Also you're using variables out of scope (declared within `if/then/else`).

Comment: You don't need to use `var` every time you're referring to a variable. You use it only once.

Comment: Thanks, Melancia, but I don't think that's going to solve the issue. Is the issue really that I'm loading too many things? If so, it's odd that it only crashes/doesn't load on a chrome refresh. Any ideas for fixing this?

Comment: What I pointed out is just to make the code _valid_. Probably won't fix your issue.

Comment: I've opened the site here about 3 minutes ago. It's still loading something.

Comment: Now one thing that is VERY odd about this, is that you can stop the page from loading if you turn one of the music files on and then off. (the triangles if you didn't know). This leads me to think it has something to do with audio loading, but I don't know how / why.

Comment: Isolating the images seems to make it work: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/d9rf1rmc/

Comment: But still, sometimes it takes ages to load. Maybe a server issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I believe I solved the issue. I put preload="none" into the audio tags, and now refreshing on chrome seems to be instant with no problems.

Comment: Just as an exercise to improve your coding skills... http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/d9rf1rmc/1/

Comment: Thanks. I declared the variables outside the if/else statement and added the semicolons.